# How create no-op version for firebase performance monitoring

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I want to use [firebase performace monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/products/performance/) in a big android multidex application, who's using modules. So I add `apply plugin` and `dependencies` to my gradle file. But my build time increased too much. So tell me how to create a no-op version in debug builds. My problem is that I don't want `apply plugin` in gradle file (because it is still BETA) in debug and release build, only in alpha build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is now proven:

```
buildTypes
{
    debug
    {
        manifestPlaceholders = [firebaseDisableMonitoring: true]
    }
    release
    {
        manifestPlaceholders = [firebaseDisableMonitoring: false]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the extra effort of the Performance Monitoring plugin using the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk#android).

Comment: I yes i see that, but figure out how to not include `apply plugin`, because I not want any code of that lib.

Comment: The apply is not relevant to adding code to the app.